# How to apply datepiker to dropdawn list

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

```
       <td class="col-lg-3">
           <select name="type_of_role" id="licence_exp_date" required="" class="form-control">
            <option value="manager">yyyy-MM-dd</option>
            <option value="supervisior">2016-05-12</option>

               <script>
                   $(function() {
                      $("#licence_exp_date").datepicker();
                          });
               </script>

          </select>
```

How to apply datepicker to dropdown list? I tried to apply but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery datepicker will not work on a dropdown list. It will work on any text based HTML input tags.

```
<input type="" >
```

If you would like to use the JQuery datepicker, I suggest you use an

```
<input type="text" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The date has to go somewhere, so I created TWO `<input>` fields -- one for datepicker, and one for non-datepicker, just to demonstrate how to trigger datepicker via the dropdown.

The jQuery code watches the dropdown and if supervisor is selected, it will `focus()` on the field that has datepicker attached to it (which triggers the pop-up calendar)

Anyway, this example shows you how to apply datepicker to only one choice from the dropdown list. Change it as required.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/q0x8epvm/)</kbd>

```js
$("#licence_exp_date").datepicker();

$('#roleSelect').change(function(){
 //alert(this.value);
 if (this.value == 'supervisor'){
  $("#licence_exp_text").val('');
  $("#licence_exp_date").css({'z-index':'2'}).focus();
 }else{
  $("#licence_exp_date").css({'z-index':'0'}).val('');
  $("#licence_exp_text").focus();
 }
});
```

```css
#dateDIV {position:relative;margin:10px 0;}
#dateDIV>input{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
#licence_exp_text{z-index:1;border:1px solid orange;}
#licence_exp_date{z-index:0;background:wheat;border:1px solid #333;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-xI/qyl9vpwWFOXz7+x/9WkG5j/SVnSw21viy8fWwbeE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
 <select id="roleSelect" name="type_of_role" required class="form-control">
  <option value="">Choose One:</option>
  <option value="manager">yyyy-MM-dd</option>
  <option value="supervisor">2016-05-12</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div id="dateDIV">
 <input id="licence_exp_text" type="text" />
 <input id="licence_exp_date" type="text" />
</div>
```